# Formals within R6Class

Tags: r, r6

I'm trying to get the formals() of a function within an R6Class. But this does not seem to work. I think there might be a problem with the environments.

```
Test <- R6Class(
  "Test",

  public = list(
    foo = function(x){
      x
    }, 

    printFormals1 = function(){
      formals("foo")
    }, 

    printFormals2 = function(){
      formals("self$foo")
    }
  )
)

test <- Test$new()
test$printFormals1()
test$printFormals2()
```

The error says:

```
Error in get(fun, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'foo' of mode 'function' was not found

Error in get(fun, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'self$foo' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Without R6Classes this is easy:

```
foo <- function(x){
  x
}

formals("foo")
```

resulting:

```
$x
```

Glad if someone could explain and help

Thank you
Michael

**edit:**

Found the solution. Not related to R6class: eval(parse(text = "self$foo")) does the job. I'm leaving the question in case someone else faces a similar problem.

```
Test <- R6Class(
  "Test",

  public = list(
    foo = function(x){
      x
    }, 

    printFormals2 = function(){
      print(formals(eval(parse(text = "self$foo"))))
    }
  )
)

test <- Test$new()

test$printFormals2()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking under the hood of `formals` you will see that it has very specific search paramaters for when you pass something that is a character not a function.

You can just pass the function [avoiding the `eval(parse(text=...))` ugliness]

```
Test <- R6Class(
  "Test",

  public = list(
    foo = function(x){
      x
    }, 

    printFormals2 = function(){
     formals(self$foo)
    }
  )
)

test <- Test$new()

test$printFormals2()
# $x
```